# Android View: How to use  "rewrite View class"  in layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

I have rewritten   `EditText` class (draw a straight line for each line of `EditText`) and call it "EditTextExtra` for example.

Now, I will use this class as other normal View ( `Button`, `EditText`,...). I can handy program it to insert to form. But, I don't know how to use this class in layout xml file as other view.

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it in the xml layout reference it using the name + package:

```
<com.package.here.EditTextExtra //attributes here />
```